# Problem connecting to RPi-4 using SSH on Wi-Fi

Tags: networking

Via ssh, I can connect my raspberry pi 4 through ethernet. But I cannot reach it through wifi.
The answer is `no route to host`.
Both machines are on Ubuntu. My computer on ubuntu 18.04 and the raspberry on ubuntu server 19.10

Comment: Is the Pi on the same subnet as your local machine's ethernet connection? Assuming your wifi and ethernet connections are on different subnets, do you have a valid gateway on the ethernet connection? Can other traffic reach the Pi but just SSH does not?

Comment: Are either machine running Ubuntu? It's not clear what Ubuntu-specific help you are seeking. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1249875/edit) to clarify.

Comment: I do not understand what a subnet is, nor a valid gateway. The Pi can get internet on wifi without problem. I can make ping connections on ethernet, but nothing if I disconnect the Rj45 plug while wifi is active.

Comment: Here is the answer to the question : "route" to the pi :

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to the question:

“Route” to the IP:

- 169.254.0.0 for wlan0 Iface, and
- 192.168.1.0 for the eth0 Iface

[image]